# Dynamically adding shapes to a panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, dynamic

Alright, i have been struggling with a specific issue. On a web page in C# i would like to build a diagram. It will consist of some rectangles (i want the rectangles to have extra functionality later, later it will have arrows and other images).

After quite some research i discovered that it is not possible to dynamically draw stuff from the c# code to the user web page.

All the things i can find tell me to make a bitmap and then save it to the outputstream or something, which i did. But it had a strange result, after clicking the button (it should build a rectangle and add it to the panel) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b3U2.jpg

code:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

//toegevoegd
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Text;

namespace Drawing.Usercontrols
{
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

        Panel Panel1 = new Panel();
        Panel Panel2 = new Panel();

        View View1 = new View(); //how does this even work

        Bitmap objBitmap = new Bitmap(400, 440);


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //adding a square... on  a Panel...
            Panel2.Width=500;
            Panel2.Height = 500;
            Panel2.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet; 
            this.Controls.Add(Panel2);

            //Making a graphicsobject from the bitmap
            Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmap);

            //objGraphics.Clear(Color.Blue);
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 3);
            Brush x = new SolidBrush(Color.BlueViolet);

            //This piece will put up a sweet ellipse on the rectangle
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200, 100, 60, 20);
            objGraphics.DrawEllipse(p, rect);

            Panel1.Controls.Add(Panel2);

            //This will add the bitmap to the page, but not really, everything on the page will dissapear and this dude will show up
            //objBitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);


            //This will add an image from the internet to the panel, which works
            //Panel2.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image { ImageUrl = String.Format("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/518rMVxp3qL._SL75_SS50_.jpg") });

            // textboxes adding
            this.Controls.Add(Panel1);

            Label FeedbackLabel = new Label();
            TextBox Inputtextbox = new TextBox();
            Button Submitbutton = new Button();

            FeedbackLabel.ID = "lblFeedback";
            FeedbackLabel.Text = "Hello world";

            Submitbutton.ID = "btnSubmit";
            Submitbutton.Text = "Submit";

            Inputtextbox.ID = "txtInput";

            Submitbutton.Click += SubmitButton_Click;

            Panel1.Controls.Add(FeedbackLabel);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(Submitbutton);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(Inputtextbox);
        }

protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this is the part where the black rectangle is drawn
    objBitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

}


    }
}
```

So my final question is: Can i build rectangles with shapes in it and place them across a panel/layout 
(later i want to use those rectangles as objects (adding onclick events to them, but i wont bother you with that just yet)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I know this code doesnt really represent what i am going for, but it is about building the stuff up.

Most stuff i found online hinted that i have to save the graphical shape to a bitmap on the server and refer to those shapes later on.

But i hope there is another solution, i couldnt get it to work.

Comment: "another solution" that is different how? You showed your semi-successful attempt, but have not specifically described what you want. The most straight-forward way to include a raster in ASP.NET page is to use ASP.NET Image server control.